# C# Plugin: access mother form and functions

Tags: c#, plugins, interface

I followed an tutorial how to make application support plugins. Everything seems to be working fine, but I need the plugin to be able to call functions and access variables in main application, not just the other way around. I have an http wrapper class that will monitor net usage etc.. for the main app. The plugin would call http wrapper from the mother application.

How can I accomplish this? Do I need to define a class with all the available functions/variables? I will also need the plugin to generate GUI, so that user can set some settings for it.

This is what I got so far:

**Main Application:**

```
namespace MainApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<iPlugin> PLUGIN_LIST = new List<iPlugin>();

        public void LoadPlugins()
        {
            // load plugins..
        }

        // how do I call this function from a plugin?!
        public void HTTP()
        {
            // do some networking stuff..
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPlugins();
        }


    }
}
```

**Plugin Interface:**

```
namespace PluginInterface
{
    public interface iPlugin
    {
        string GetPluginName();

        void callHTTP();

        void SerVar(string var);
    }
}
```

**The Plugin:**

```
namespace MyPlugin
{
    public class Main : iPlugin
    {
        string variable = "";

        public string GetPluginName()
        {
            return "MyPlugin";
        }

        public void callHTTP(){
            MainApplication.HTTP(); // call HTTP in main application
        }

        public void SerVar(string var)
        {
            variable = var;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when I followed the tutorial, plugin interface was a seperate project, which I had to 'add as reference' in both MainApplication and myPlugin. Does that mean that my application and plugin are dependent on pluginInterface.dll? or it is just needed for development? if they're depended in runtime, how can I define it in both, my app and plugin, so that I don't have to use extra dll? Hope that makes sense, Thanks!

**EDIT: Full MainApplication code**

```
public interface iPlugin
{
    string GetPluginName();

    string GetInformation();

    void SerVar(string var);
}


namespace MainApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<iPlugin> PLUGIN_LIST = new List<iPlugin>();

        public void LoadPlugins()
        {

            string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName;
            string pluginDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\Plugins";

            foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(pluginDir, "*.dll"))
            {
                // THIS LINE GIVES THE ERROR
                Type[] pluginTypes = Assembly.LoadFile(s).GetTypes();

                foreach (Type t in pluginTypes)
                {
                    if (t.ToString().Contains("Main"))
                    {
                        iPlugin plugin = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as iPlugin;

                        PLUGIN_LIST.Add(plugin);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadPlugins();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you could take is to define an interface that contains all the methods that you would like to call from the mother application (called say `IMother`), and make the mother application implement this.

Then you could update `IPlugin` to have a method like `void SetMother( IMother mother )` and when you load each plugin you could call this method on the plugin.  That way each plugin would have the `IMother` reference from the beginning and could call methods as necessary.

Regarding your question on plugininterface.dll, yes, both MainApplication and myPlugin are dependent on that dll (it is not just needed for development).  If you want to avoid using an extra dll (having references to extra dlls isn't generally an issue) I would put the plugin interface in the same project as MainApplication.  I'm not sure if I'm understanding your layout though, so if that doesn't answer your question please add more details as to how your projects/solution is configured.

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:

I assume your layout is something like the following:
One solution file that contains three projects
One project for MainApplication
One project for myPlugin
One project for the plugin interface.

You could move the code files for the plugin interface into the MainApplication project.  That way MainApplication would not be dependent on anything else.  Just take the .cs file from the plugin interface project and add it to MainApplication.  You would then need to reference MainApplication from myPlugin, but that should be ok.

Comment: plugin interface in the main app project would make more sense I think.

Comment: Thanks csm! I would just like to use as less dll's as possibly can, because the application itself is going to be single exe. When user downloads it, the app is gonna download all the plugins and save them in a dir. If main application is dependent on pluginInterface.dll, then it's not gonna work and I will need to use another application that is not dependent on anything to do all the work, which I don't want to do. Can you show me how can I define the pluginInterface in main application and the plugin using the code I provided please? thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm gonna try it out now!

Comment: I got a problem, when I put iPlugin interface into main application and remove reference from pluginInterface.dll, I get "Unable to load one or more of the requested types" on the line "Type[] pluginTypes = Assembly.LoadFile(s).GetTypes();" the line is in "LoadPlugins" function. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.  I'm guessing that `s` in this case is one of the plugin dlls.  Did you update the myPlugin project to have a reference to MainApplication?

Comment: How do I do that? I though adding the same interface class (iPlugin) shoud do the trick. I got two projects now, main application and plugin, both have interface iPlugin added to them.

Comment: You only want one version of the iPlugin class.  Having two copies of it will cause issues (even if they are the same interface).  I would remove the file from the plugin project, and then on the plugin project -> references -> right click and select add reference.  Add the project reference to main application.  Make sense?

Comment: Thanks! When I'm adding reference I select the compiled mainapplication.exe correct? I edited my post, that's the full source for my application, I commented the line that's giving me problems, if you could take a look at it that would be great. thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could do it that way by selecting the compiled mainapplication.exe.  I'm thinking the problem with loading the types is that iPlugin is still defined in both mainapplication and in the plugin project.  I would add the reference to plugin and make sure that compiles successfully.  If it does, then I would think that as long as the new dll is in the Plugins\ directory it should work.  If you want, you can post a zip or whatever of you code on skydrive or something and I can take a look at it.  Or provide your email address and then I'll send you an email and you can reply with your code

Comment: Thank you! After I put in the new myplugin.dll in the directory it worked. I'm confused on why would it give an error if the dll is invalid? is that normal? if I would have some random *.dlls from somewhere else, that would make my application crash?

Comment: I think the issue was that the iPlugin interface with the same namespace was defined in both your app and the plugin dll, so it caused an error when the dll tried to load.  This could happen if there is a random dll in that folder but I would think the chance would be slim that it would happen.  You could introduce a naming scheme to your plugin dlls to help prevent this issue, so instead of searching for *.dll you could search for *-plugin.dll or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different than anything else.  Give your plugin a reference to the form.

As for the .dll dependancy, yes.. both the plugin and application would be dependant.  But this is not a bad thing.  In fact, its very very good.  I would't change that bit of architecture at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new interface, say IHostPlugin and expose the properties of the main form you want to use in your plugin via this interface. Implement the interface in your main form class, or better, in a wrapper class that has access to your main form. Make this class marshalByref and pass it to your plugin by creating a method on your plugin's interface that takes this host interface as a parameter so that you plugin has a reference to the host.

You should keep these interfaces in a separate dll so that you dont have type mismatches accross app domains. There is no reason why you cant put this into a solution and reference the project.

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to compile the dll into an exe?

Comment: Not a good idea. You want your interfaces to be shared by all the assemblies you load in each AppDomain otherwise you will get type missmatches when you try to instantiate them. Just add a reference to the dll.